# Calling a service via Ajax Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying yo make a call to my service but it's not finding it for some reason and I think its because I am not calling it the right way:

How can I add to the response the possible error?, so that i get a better idea.. all i am getting is call is failed because i have this in both functions:

```
function successFunc(response) {

    if (200 == response.status) {
        alert("Call is success");
    }
}

function failureFunc(response) {

    alert("Call is failed");

}
```

Comment: Can you call your web service manually? (I mean, open the link to your asmx in a browser, and try to call the EnableALL function.)

Comment: Yes i can it asks for the parameters

Comment: You fill up this.MyParams, but you POST this.OauthParams. Is this just a typo?

Comment: Yeah typo, question in the failureFunc, is there a way to get a more descriptive error in that alert?

Comment: var s = ""; for (var p in response) { s += "<b>" + p + ":</b><br />" + response[p] + "<br />"; } ...and put s into a <div>!

Comment: It says its missing param1 .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for clients accessing your web service through Ajax, you will have to add this attribute declaration to your web service:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]
```

You can read more about it at [ScriptServiceAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx)